# Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465" Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I am trying to send contact us from from Laravel application

I did it in local and i was able to send emails to Mailtrap and gmail

But when i uploaded the application to Linux host i face this error:

```
Connection could not be established with host "smtp.gmail.com:587": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (Network is unreachable)
```

[image]

.env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

i tried to change the values to:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

also didn't work and i get the same error

I tried using my mailtrap account and also same problem

I turned on "less secure apps" in gmail

here is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    // validate fields
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', new NoHtml],
        'email' => ['required', 'email', new NoHtml],
        'city' => ['required', 'string', new NoHtml],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', new NoHtml],
        'activity' => ['required', 'string', new NoHtml],
        'fullName' => ['required', 'string', new NoHtml],
        'g-recaptcha-response' => ['required', new GoogleRecaptcha]
    ]);



    // redirect to contact form with message
    session()->flash('success', 'Message is sent! We will get back to you soon!');

    Mail::send( new ContactFormMessage() );

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

ContactFormMessage:

```
public function build(Request $request){

    return $this->from([
            'address' => $request->email,
            'name' => $request->name
        ])
        ->to( env('APP_ADMIN_CONTACT') )
        ->subject( 'Message from website: ' . $request->subject )
        ->view('emails.contactform')
        ->with([
            'contactName' => $request->name,
            'contactCity' => $request->city,
            'contactEmail' => $request->email,
            'contactPhone' => $request->phone,
            'contactActivityType' => $request->activity,
            'contactFullName' => $request->fullName,
        ]);

}
```

Why is it working on local for both mails, mailtrap and gmail but on host i face this problem?

I tried a lot of solutions like changing values in .env file and tried to clear cache and config but with no luck

am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Previously there were option in google to turn on the 'Less Secure Apps' but this setting is no more available. So there is another approach to configure SMTP settings by enabling 2 Factor Authentciation.

Comment: i enabled 2 factor in gmail
and i turned on "less secure apps" from google admin console 
still same problem

Comment: Try Mailtrap : https://mailtrap.io/home